# How to parse this tree structured json response to form recycler tree view in android?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, nested, treeview

Here is sample json response

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Folders List Found.",
  "list": [
    {
      "folder_id": "25",
      "folder_unique": "MjU=",
      "folder_name": "MichelleF",
      "folder_url": "",
      "parent_id": "1",
      "user_id": "ADMN-000085",
      "site_id": "ADMN-SITE-000001",
      "level": "0",
      "folder_added_datetime": "2019-07-31 16:43:02",
      "folder_updated_datetime": "2019-07-31 16:43:02",
      "status": "Active",
      "children": [
        {
          "folder_id": "26",
          "folder_unique": "MjY=",
          "folder_name": "Inbox",
          "folder_url": "",
          "parent_id": "25",
          "user_id": "ADMN-000085",
          "site_id": "ADMN-SITE-000001",
          "level": "0",
          "folder_added_datetime": "2019-07-31 16:43:02",
          "folder_updated_datetime": "2019-07-31 16:43:02",
          "status": "Active",
          "children": [
            
          ]
        },
        {
          "folder_id": "27",
          "folder_unique": "Mjc=",
          "folder_name": "Trash",
          "folder_url": "",
          "parent_id": "25",
          "user_id": "ADMN-000085",
          "site_id": "ADMN-SITE-000001",
          "level": "0",
          "folder_added_datetime": "2019-07-31 16:43:02",
          "folder_updated_datetime": "2019-07-31 16:43:02",
          "status": "Active",
          "children": [
            
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please give me any solution to parse this and show like this below image example recycler tree structure. This is purely dynamic adding folders and response also changed every time.

[image: e]

Comment: Use GSON for parse the data using the POJO.
https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Hii @Jaymin thanks for ur reply..Please give any code sample to using gson to form recycler view tree structure I am new to android...Please help me

Comment: Here is the example.https://www.zoftino.com/handling-json-using-gson-in-android

Comment: is it possible to parse the above JSON response to show multilevel recycler view in android by using gson library?

Comment: Yes, you need to build the login according to your need.